# Count the number of packets with pyshark

Tags: python, wireshark, packet-sniffers, wireshark-dissector, pyshark

In this code with pyshark

```
import pyshark
cap = pyshark.FileCapture(filename)
i = 0
for idx, packet in enumerate(cap):
    i += 1
print i
print len(cap._packets)
```

`i` and `len(cap._packets)` give two different results. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A look at the [source code](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/blob/master/src/pyshark/capture/file_capture.py) reveals that `_packets` is a list containing packets and is only used internally:

When iterating through a `FileCapture` object with `keep_packets = True` packets are getting added to this list.

---

To get access to all packets in a `FileCapture` object you should iterate over it just like you did:

```
for packet in cap:
    do_something(packet)
```

But to count the amount of packets just do this:

```
packet_amount = len(cap)
```

or use a counter like you did, but **don't use** `_packets` as it does not contain the complete packet list.

Comment: packet_amount = len(cap) is returning 0 in python 3.8 and 3.9

Answer (score 12):

Don't know if it works in Python 2.7, but in Python 3.4 `len(cap)` returns 0.
The FileCapture object is a generator, so what worked for me is `len([packet for packet in cap])`

Comment: Why i get `    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running') 
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running` when running  `len([packet for packet in cap])`?

Comment: I face same problem, it returns 0 in python 3.8 and 3.9 also

Answer (score 8):

i too, len(cap) is 0, i thinks the answer is fail.
if you want know len(cap), please load packet before print it.
use: cap.load_packets()

```
cap.load_packets()
packet_amount = len(cap)
print packet_amount
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another way using callback function. Also little bit faster approach.

```
length = 0 
def count_callback(pkt):
    global length
    length = length + 1

cap.apply_on_packets(count_callback)

print(length)
```